# Content package plugin fails on TeamCity

Tags: maven, aem

Recently encountered an issue plaguing local AEM deployment, namely the `content-package-maven-plugin` sometimes fails with the following error:

**[ERROR] Missing response status information in response**

Updating the `content-package-maven-plugin` to version `0.5.24` and Maven to `3.5.2`, as it was required by the plugin, resolves the error on local environment.

When building the same code on TeamCity the `content-package-maven-plugin`  plugin throws an error:

```
Filter root's ancestor '/apps' is not covered by any of the specified dependencies.
```

We're using AEM 6.3, and TeamCity has the appropriate Maven version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem, try using

    `<plugin>
    ...
        <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        ...
        <configuration>
            ...
            <packageType>container</packageType>
            <embeddedTarget>${package.root}/install/</embeddedTarget>`

With packageType container it seems to work.

Comment: For some reason I haven't seen this earlier, I'll take a look if this works.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in filevault plugin. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCRVLT-219

Temporary fix: under filevault-package-maven-plugin, provide the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
 ...
  <failOnDependencyErrors>false</failOnDependencyErrors>
</configuration>
```